# Dnscrypt doesn't work for me

Tags: archlinux

I don't know why dnscrypt doesn't work for me.

I have installed DNSmasq and DNScrypt from arch repositories (and not AUR)

```
~  cat /etc/resolv.conf  
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 127.0.0.1:53

~  cat /etc/dnsmasq.conf
domain-needed
bogus-priv
resolv-file=/etc/resolv-dnsmasq.conf 
listen-address=127.0.0.1
bind-interfaces
dhcp-range=192.168.1.10,192.168.1.20,255.255.255.0,4d
cache-size=300

~  cat /etc/resolv-dnsmasq.conf 
nameserver 127.0.0.2:53

~  cat  cat /etc/conf.d/dnscrypt-proxy 
DNSCRYPT_LOCALIP=127.0.0.2
DNSCRYPT_LOCALPORT=53
DNSCRYPT_USER=nobody
DNSCRYPT_PROVIDER_NAME=2.dnscrypt-cert.resolver2.dnscrypt.eu
DNSCRYPT_PROVIDER_KEY=3748:5585:E3B9:D088:FD25:AD36:B037:01F5:520C:D648:9E9A:DD52:1457:4955:9F0A:9955
DNSCRYPT_RESOLVERIP=77.66.84.233
DNSCRYPT_RESOLVERPORT=443

~  sudo systemctl status dnscrypt-proxy
[sudo] password for ****: 
● dnscrypt-proxy.service - A tool for securing communications between a client and a DNS resolver.
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dnscrypt-proxy.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2014-06-19 13:30:59 IRDT; 1h 6min ago
 Main PID: 581 (dnscrypt-proxy)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dnscrypt-proxy.service
           └─581 /usr/bin/dnscrypt-proxy --local-address=127.0.0.2:53 --resolver-address=77.66.84.233:443 --provider-name=2.dnscrypt-cert.resolver2.dnscryp...

Jun 19 13:31:00 raspberrypi dnscrypt-proxy[581]: [INFO] Server certificate #808464433 received
Jun 19 13:31:00 raspberrypi dnscrypt-proxy[581]: [INFO] This certificate looks valid
Jun 19 13:31:00 raspberrypi dnscrypt-proxy[581]: [INFO] Chosen certificate #808464433 is valid from [2014-01-12] to [2015-01-12]
Jun 19 13:31:00 raspberrypi dnscrypt-proxy[581]: [INFO] Server key fingerprint is C863:1F2D:C621:3FE8:CD02:C65A:6DB6:DDD6:08BA:49EA:5962:AF4C:B063:...A4C:9925
Jun 19 13:31:00 raspberrypi dnscrypt-proxy[581]: [NOTICE] Proxying from 127.0.0.2:53 to 77.66.84.233:443
Jun 19 14:31:49 raspberrypi dnscrypt-proxy[581]: [INFO] Refetching server certificates
Jun 19 14:31:49 raspberrypi dnscrypt-proxy[581]: [INFO] Server certificate #808464433 received
Jun 19 14:31:49 raspberrypi dnscrypt-proxy[581]: [INFO] This certificate looks valid
Jun 19 14:31:49 raspberrypi dnscrypt-proxy[581]: [INFO] Chosen certificate #808464433 is valid from [2014-01-12] to [2015-01-12]
Jun 19 14:31:49 raspberrypi dnscrypt-proxy[581]: [INFO] Server key fingerprint is C863:1F2D:C621:3FE8:CD02:C65A:6DB6:DDD6:08BA:49EA:5962:AF4C:B063:...A4C:9925
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.

~  ping www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com

~
```

There is no problem with DNSmasq,It works correctly I have tested it by Comodo DNS

Thank you.